# Unnavoidable Illegal Forward Reference

Tags: java, oop, initialization, forward-reference

I am having this issue I can't seem to resolve:
I am trying to create a network of 'Location' objects. Each Location has a name and is connected to other 'adjacentLocations'. However, because it references adjacentLocations, I cannot initialize each Location Object fully because the adjacentLocations still need to be initialized.

I am coding in Java, a sample of what I mean is below:

```
public class Location{
    private String name;
    private Location[] adjacentLocations;

    public Location(String name, Location[] adjacentLocations){
        this.name = name;
        this.adjacentLocations = adjacentLocations;
    }
    Location bar = new Location("bar",new Location[]{townSquare, dock});
    Location townSquare = new Location("town square",new Location[]{dock, bar});
    Location dock = new Location("dock", new Location[]{bar, townSquare});
}
```

I do not plan on accessing the contents of the adjacent Locations until the whole "map" is initialized.
I have tried putting the code in a main method, it complains that it `cannot resolve symbol townSquare`.
I have tried declaring all the Locations and initializing within a main method, and it complains that `townSquare may have not been initialized`.
I have tried the above code which complains `illegal forward reference`

I know I could try initializing all of my Locations with empty adjacent Locations and then adding them in post, but that seems like anything but elegant, and a pain in the butt. Am I missing something obvious? I tried looking up all of those error codes and did not find a useful solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously can not construct object which depend on stuff *that does not yet exist*. What you have created is a chicken-and-egg problem thats hard to solve in any language.

A good choice would be to manage adjacency externally, e.g. through adjacency lists:

```java
class TownMap {
    Map<Location, List<Location>> adjacency = new HashMap<>();

    public void addLocation(Location location) {
        adjacency.putIfAbsent(location, new ArrayList());
    }

    public void addNeighbor(Location a, Location b) {
        adjacency.computeIfAbsent(a, new ArrayList<>()).add(b);
        adjacency.computeIfAbsent(b, new ArrayList<>()).add(a);
    }

    public List<Location> getNeighbours(Location location) {
        return Collections.immutableList(adjacency.get(location));
    }
}
```

You can of couse also initialize the `adjacentLocations` empty and set them later, once those adjacent locations have indeed been constructed.

You can hide the mechanism from callers by creating an interface:

```java
public interface Location {
    public String name();
    public List<Location> neighbours(); 
}

private class LocationImpl implements Location {
    private String name;
    private List<Location> neighbours;

   protected void addNeighbour(Location location) {
        neighbours.add(location);
   }
   
   public List<Location> neighbours() {
       return Collections.immutableList(this.neighbours);
   }
   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    LocationImpl bar = new LocationImpl("bar");
    LocationImpl docks = new LocationImpl("docks");
    LocationImpl townsquare = new LocationImpl("townsquare");
    bar.addNeighbour(docks);
    docks.setNeighbour(bar);
    // etc.

    locations.Add(bar);
    locations.add(docks);
    locations.add(townsquare);

   // give whomever you want the List<Location> which they can't manipulate further
}
```

With proper visibility rules and modules set up, no one can manipulate these objects further.